# SQL: Updating a user ordered sequence of items within a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table for storing items, in a particular order, associated with a container. Separate ak_* constraints involving item_id and seq ensure a container contains distinct items and the sequence of those items is distinct.

```
CREATE TABLE [container_items] (
    [container_item_id] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [container_id]  INT NOT NULL,
    [item_id]    INT NOT NULL,
    [seq]        INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_container_item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([container_item_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [ak_container_item_seq] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([container_id] ASC, [seq] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [ak_container_item_item] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([container_id] ASC, [item_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_container_item_item] FOREIGN KEY ([item_id]) REFERENCES [items] ([item_id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_container_item_container] FOREIGN KEY ([container_id]) REFERENCES [containers] ([container_id])
);
```

Suppose for container_id=1 the original data is

```
container_item_id, container_id, item_id, seq
1,1,1,1
2,1,3,2
3,1,10,3
4,1,8,4
```

and some client app for reordering says the new sequence for the item_ids is

```
8,1
10,2
3,3
1,4
```

The ak_* constraints make it impossible to update the data base table directly. For instance, trying update in this manner:

```
update container
container_items
set item_id=8, seq=1
where container_item_id = 1
```

fails

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ak_container_item_item. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'container_items'. The duplicate key value is (1, 8).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Q: Is it worth the effort to find an algorithm that would reuse existing container_item_id records when the seq order is changed ?

A non-reusing approach would be to delete the existing records for survery_id=1 and then append the new sequenced item_ids as new records.

Comment: I can not see `survey_id` and `survey_item_id` in your table

Comment: Essentially only  `[seq]` needs to be updated for reordering. Try two steps update  - first update old  `[seq]` shifting in by 100 (just for example, it should be a computed value really) and then updating to the needed values under 100.

Comment: Hi Radim, survey is an artficat from moving from my actual problem to a stack overflow question.  survey changed to container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *encapsulate* the whole operation in a simple atomic **transaction**. Also, you need a at least one 'aux' value, I a couple of aux values with simple `* -1` operation in this sample:

```
begin transaction tx1;
set transaction isolation level serializable;

update container
survey_items
set seq=-1*seq             #<-- set aux values
where container_id = 1;

update container
survey_items
set seq=1
where container_id = 1 and item_id = 8;

update container
survey_items
set seq=2
where container_id = 1 and item_id = 10;

#and so on

commit;
```

Notice than you can work at `repeatable read` with the same guaranties because no [phantoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Phantom_reads) are made.